# JUnit custom Runner which can inject between Statements in test

Tags: java, testing, junit, inject

i got a question if it is possible to create a Runner for this:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)

public class Class1Test {
@Test public void test2() {
    doSomething();
    assertTrue(something);
    doSomethingElse();
    assertTrue(somethingElse);
    }
}
```

The Runner should make a log after every call / assertion in the test.

```
public class MyRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    public MyRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

/* Here should be an method that just executed the calls/assertions but log everything */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible because the test methods aka [Statements](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/model/Statement.html) are the smallest units visible to JUnit.

You can log the calls to JUnit's `Assert`class by wrapping it and doing the logging in your wrapper.